# How to make HybridWebView go back when device back button is pressed

Tags: android-webview, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with a HybridWebView and a HybridWebViewRenderer in the Droid project.

I am trying to make the web view navigate back when the device's back button is pressed.

It looks pretty simple if I was just using a Xamarin.Forms WebView within my page. I would just do it like this...

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    _webView.GoBack();
    return true;
}
```

But the HybridWebView does not have a GoBack() method.

In my Droid project, the only place where I have access to the WebView is in the HybridWebViewRenderer but I cannot listen for the OnBackButtonPressed event here.

Anyone know how I can make a HybridWebView navigate back when the device's back button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `window.history.back();` from Javascript might be a dirty solution.

Also, calling the renderer's method from a PCL class should not be a problem.

The PCL class:

```
public class MyHybridWebView : HybridWebView
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DoSomeNative;

    public void CallNative()
    {
        DoSomeNative(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The renderer:

```
public class MyHybridWebViewRenderer : HybridWebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        (e.NewElement as MyHybridWebView).DoSomeNative += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //Do something
            //Don't forget to unsubscribe in Dispose
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to use the code you provided to capture OnBackPressed in themain activity and handle it in the rended in the DoSomeNative event handler.

Comment: Any idea how this could be done for checking "CanGoBack" for the HybridWebView? I am getting stuck on how I would return the bool back to the calling class in the PCL

Comment: @RyanMendoza You might check how it is implemented in Xamarin.Forms WebView.

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin have they done this in their library for WKWebView?

Comment: @RyanMendoza I don't remember tbh. Anyway, I wouldn't recommend to use HybridWebView from XLabs since it's no longer supported. You're probably have to implement it manually, it's not so difficult in fact.

Answer (score 0):

My solution that is working are as follows:

HybridWebView that extends the View:
I created 2 event listeners and 1 bool property.

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> GoBackOnNativeEventListener;
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> CanGoBackOnNativeEventListener;
public bool _CanGoBack { get; set; }
```

Methods:

```
public bool GoBack()
{
    GoBackOnNative();
    return true;
}
private void GoBackOnNative()
{
    GoBackOnNativeEventListener(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
public bool CanGoBack()
{
    CanGoBackOnNative();
    return _CanGoBack;
}
private void CanGoBackOnNative()
{
    CanGoBackOnNativeEventListener(this, EventArgs.Empty);            
}
```

In iOS render
public class WebViewRender : HybridWebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                InitializeCommands((ClickableWebView)e.NewElement);
            }
        }

```
    private void InitializeCommands(ClickableWebView element)
    {
        element.RefreshCommand = () =>
        {
            Control?.Reload();
        };

        element.GoBackCommand = () =>
        {
            var ctrl = Control;
            if (ctrl == null)
                return;

            if (ctrl.CanGoBack)
                ctrl.GoBack();
        };

        element.CanGoBackFunction = () =>
        {
            var ctrl = Control;
            if (ctrl == null)
                return false;

            return ctrl.CanGoBack;
        };

        element.CanGoForwardFunction = () =>
        {
            var ctrl = Control;
            if (ctrl == null)
                return false;

            return ctrl.CanGoForward;
        };
        element.GoFrowardCommand = () =>
        {
            var ctrl = Control;
            if (ctrl == null)
                return;

            if (ctrl.CanGoForward)
                ctrl.GoForward();
        };
    }
}
```

On renderer I bind the listener:

```
e.NewElement.GoBackOnNativeEventListener += (sender, args) =>
{
    Control.GoBack(); 
};
e.NewElement.CanGoBackOnNativeEventListener += (sender, args) =>
{
    _cangoback = Control.CanGoBack();
    var hybridWebView = Element as HybridWebView;
    hybridWebView._CanGoBack = _cangoback;
};
```

Finally on xaml.cs, on method OnBackButtonPressed(), I do like:

```
if (hybridWebView.CanGoBack())
{
    hybridWebView.GoBack();
    return true;
}
else
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
```